# Mediation with hierarchical regression using STATA

Tags: regression, mediation

I had run the mediation test using hierarchical regression.
My sample is comprised of two years of data with a total of 976 companies.

> **Question:
>   Do I need to run the bootstrap in the mediation test? I found that articles are not run the bootstrap. Additionally, I tried to run the bootstrap and I found the results were the same except on the standard error value.**

Thanks in advance for your time to answer me

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please provide more details on your study, especially on the model you are testing. Is it full or partial mediation? Serial or parallel mediation? This should increase the chance of you getting a response

Comment: Thanks, the mediating variables itself is not significant.